# Adding external omni directional antenna to Nanostation Loco M2

Tags: ieee-802.11

I bought a Nanostation Loco M2 which does not have an UFL to SMA(f) RP port for me to add an external antenna.

I bought these UFL to SMA(f) RP cables and an external antenna but I am not sure where or how to attach them.

[Having seen this post](http://arg-wireless.com.ar/index.php?topic=920.0) which needs Google translate by the way, I am not sure whether I just attached the cable to the J5/J6 port, or solder the wire on to the J9 port. Has anyone had any experience with this? Here is a picture of the circuit board:

[image: Nanostation Loco M2 board]

Comment: Return the Nano Loco M2 and buy a Rocket M2 which is built to do what you want, no hack jobs required. Though an omni is very rarely a good choice in long-range WiFi...

Comment: it's not for long range just need wide coverage and wrong devices were ordered which we cant send back due to tym constraints @Ecnerwal

Comment: through careful soldering the process actually worked. instructions URL coming soon

Comment: You should add an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: answered, check. consider getting Rockets instead @RonMaupin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I started my practicals I was working with the [NanoStation 2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiY0Zvf4cXVAhUNOsAKHee7BdgQFgguMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.ubnt.com%2Fns2_datasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH7dG6I4VVlP8icwmb8BOlx_mnb9g), a very old model from the Ubiquiti line of products. It was possible on these devices to connect an antenna.
It is no longer possible to mount antennae on any of the Nanostation models.
We soldered pigtail cables on a Nanostation Loco M2 device and it did not help to boost the signal, matter of fact signal quality dropped a tiny bit, these devices cannot power up such antennae. The  For external antennae connectivity consider getting Ubiquiti Rockets instead.